# login to a website and after login upload file using curl

Tags: php, curl, upload, multipartform-data

I want to login to a site and then upload a file using curl

I have successfully logged into website, now i want to upload a file using the same curl connection. Is it possible?

My code so far:

```
$id ='myusername';
$password ='mypassword';
$cookie_file_path = "cookie.txt";
$agent =$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$getfile='http://archive.org/download/TestVideo_935/Backntro.mp4';
$getfile=file_get_contents($getfile);
$POSTFIELDS = array(
    'username'=>$id,
    'password'=>$password,
    'uploadfile'=>'@'.$getfile  
    );
//post info for login
$LOGINURL = "http://****.com/**/;
$reffer = "http://*****.com/***/";//path to upload file 

//in my case I want to upload video as this site is video site

$ch = curl_init ($LOGINURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        "Content-Type:multipart/form-data",
));

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array("Expect:"));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, $reffer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);

print_r($info);
print_r($result);
```

any help will be greatly appreciated  !! Thanks very much !

```
         <form method="post" action="userfiles" enctype="multipart/form-data">

             <div class="formrow">

<label for="uploadfile">File</label>

<input type="file" name="uploadfile" id="uploadfile" />

 <span id="note_uploadfile"></span></div>

   <div class="formrow"><label for="uploadname">

Name</label><input type="text" name="uploadname" id="uploadname" /> <span 

          <div class="submitrow"><label></label>

</form>
```

Comment: Did you write it in [whitespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_%28programming_language%29)?

Comment: Automated logins always raise a ton of red flags.

Comment: actually I am facing problem formating code..It'll be come shortly

Comment: This is my full code.. sorry for late response

Comment: If your question is *Is it possible?*, then the answer is *Yes, it is possible*. You need to do two requests (two `curl_exec($ch);`) on the same `$ch` with different params. First - login, second - file posting.

Comment: ya i know it's possible but please give me idea of it.. I have just logged in but i could't file upload !